# migrate plus move existing biztalk server database from sql server 2008 R2 to sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, biztalk

we are planning to move biztalk database from one place to another as well as upgrade the sql server.

the initial database is in sql server 2008 R2 and target is sql server 2012.
but the thing is that we have to set up database on another system,
i tried to search it on msdn but they are providing reference to upgrade from 2005 to 2008 , or moving database from one server to another.
do you think that will work in my case !!

i found this article.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378547%28v=bts.10%29.aspx
relating to upgrading as well as moving..
but this is quite older one.

how can i upgrade as well as move biztalk database from sql server 2008 R2 to sql server 2012 on a different system (side by side upgrade).

do i have to follow same steps as upgrading a normal database from sql server 2008R2 to sql server 2012 or some other one ??

Comment: ...and which version of Biztalk do you have?  As far as I know, only Biztalk 2013+ supports SQL 2012, which is probably why there's no information about upgrading older versions of Biztalk to run on SQL 2012.

Comment: I am upgrading to biztalk 2013 as well.
previously i was having biztalk 2006.

Comment: Why to BizTalk 2013 rather than 2013 r2 or even 2016?

Answer (score 0):

If you're upgrading more than one version of BizTalk you need to just install thew new version and create a new BizTalk environment. Then take each solution and upgrade it in the correct version of Visual Studio and then install it on the new instance(s).   Anything else just isn't supported by Microsoft.
In your case you may even need an intermediate version of Visual Studio as per [Migration from Biztalk server 2006 to 2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9ac6b6c-3dbe-487b-85c5-448d257d62f4/migration-from-biztalk-server-2006-to-2013?forum=biztalkgeneral)

In fact sometimes even when you are just upgrading one version of BizTalk, it is still better to go down to clean install path as some BizTalk upgrades have had issues which could be avoided by a clean install. Migrating each application with a clean install one by one is lower risk as well, as you can test each application as you move it, rather than a big bang approach.